# can't uninstall exchange 2016 management tools on windows 10

Tags: exchange-2016

I tried to uninstall exchange 2016 management tools from windows 10 but failed and forced to exit.

[image: Exchange 2016 management tools]

Then, I run exchange 2016 setup and got following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do a reboot, then launch the Exchange installation ISO file, run “PowerShell” as Administrator, navigate to the Exchange installation file location in PS, try this command:

```
Setup.exe /mode:Uninstall /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms
```

Comment: I followed step by step but i got following error message in powershell.
'File C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\ExSetup.exe does not exist!'

Comment: Is the management tool removed? In my testing, I also got the error at the last line, but the management tool was removed successfully.

Comment: yes management tool was removed but i want to reinstall again.

Comment: If you want to install again, you could rerun the setup file in the Exchange installation media.
Do you get any error during the installation process?

Comment: yes when i re-run setup file i got this 
'File C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\ExSetup.exe does not exist!'

Comment: You could first try to delete the left “Exchange server” folder under “C:\Program Files\Microsoft”, then reinstall. Please refer to this article:
https://msptechs.com/how-to-install-exchange-server-2016-management-tools-on-windows-10/